# jira soap create issue does not contain a definition for setSummary

Tags: c#, soap, jira

I want to create issue. Wsdl can be found [here](https://jira.fcrmedia.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl). I have created client using Visual Studio and c#. 
I can login

```
JiraSoapServiceService jiraSoapService = new JiraSoapServiceService(); 
jiraSoapService.login(jiraLogin, jiraPassword);
```

I can get information

```
jiraSoapService.getIssue(auth, key);
```

but I can not create an issue

```
RemoteIssue issue = new RemoteIssue(); 
issue.setSummary(SUMMARY_NAME);
```

as it gives me `JIRA_API.box.RemoteIssue` does not contain a definition for `setSummary`. Whats is wrong?

Comment: Error seems pretty descriptive.. There is also a method `createIssue` based on the WSDL xml.

Comment: Yep, there is such method jiraSoapService.createIssue(token, issue); but I need to set summary, component and other before I call this method.

Comment: In here http://www.j-tricks.com/tutorials/issue-via-soap I can see methods are being used, but why these methods are missing in my case?

Comment: Well, the tutorial is 4 years old, it's possible JIRA has changed their API.

Comment: I got it. All good now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RemoteIssue issue = new RemoteIssue();
            issue.project = "[NAME]";
            issue.key="[KEY]";
            issue.type = "3";
            RemoteComponent component = new RemoteComponent();
            component.name = "[COMPONENT_NAME]";
            issue.components = (new RemoteComponent[] { component });
            issue.summary = "[SUMMARY]";
            issue.assignee = "[ASSIGNEE]";
            RemoteIssue returnedIssue = jiraSoapService.createIssue(token, issue);
```